# Regular Expression in C++/ Star Problem

Tags: c++, regex

I have no idea why the regular expression does not match the string below:

```
int main(){

    string seq = "0010110";
    regex rgx("((1*(01)*1*)*)(00)(1*(01)*1*)*(10)");

    cout<<regex_match(seq, rgx)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is resolved when I remove the last star, which multiplies a big string.

Please help me.

Comment: It works [in ruby](http://rubular.com/r/uzbpVkizPh). Are you sure it really fails to match?

Comment: It works for me, too.  RegexBuddy reports a successful match in 65 steps.  If I remove the last star it only takes 24 steps to match.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a quirk of your library (or usage) in treating the regex greedily. `(00)` gets 00 `(1*(01)*1*)*` sucks up `1011` and then the remaining `(10)` doesn't match the one last 0. Then for some reason your library isn't deciding to backtrack and try another match (thanks @Paul Rubel, @marcog).

Comment: but when the match fails it should backtrack, giving up the last 1 and trying to rematch. Side note, it works for me in ruby as written.

Comment: Unless this is some specific quirk of the regex library OP is using, this is *not* true. A greedy match only matches as much as it can while still allowing the full pattern to match.